# MySQL. Can't insert russian characters into column with a type VARCHAR(45)

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

I have a problem when trying to execute this line in MySQL (Workbench):

```
INSERT INTO classification (`Type`, `Subtype`) VALUES ("тип", "подтип");
```

I have tried to set different charsets for table `classification` : cp1251, utf-8, utf8mb4, cp1251_bin.

This is a table with all charsets in my database that I have found, maybe it will help you:

[image]

**UPD.** I have found a solution. However, I had to change my table, so now the table `risk` is an edited table `classification`. The result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE risk` is:

```
 'CREATE TABLE `risk` (
  `IdRisk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdSubtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Content` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdRisk`),
  KEY `FK_subtype_risk_idx` (`IdSubtype`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_subtype_risk` FOREIGN KEY (`IdSubtype`) REFERENCES `subtype` (`IdSubtype`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Can't find the solution to this issue. I'm hope that someone knows a solution to it.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you try the nvarchar instead of varchar ? or I think even text would do it

Comment: Seems like it works with nvarchar type! ty so much.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CHARACTER SET` for the table is the *default* for columns in the table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify what the columns are set to.

What is the encoding of the bytes in the client?  `cp1251` is different than `utf8`; `utf8mb4` == `utf8` for Russian.

In what way are things bad?  Based on the symptom, see [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for specific tips on what *else* might be set incorrectly.

Perhaps it was your change to `NVARCHAR` that forced `CHARACTER SET utf8` on the columns?

Comment: Yes, you are right! `NVARCHAR` automatically generate the set-expression `CHARACTER SET utf8` for column. I have edited my question by adding the result of `show create table`, check it out please.

Comment: I have one more question for you: If I need to get a string from `html-form` with `utf8` encoding for feeling the table, will it be ok without setting the charset for html-page? or I have to change it?

Comment: I filed a bug report related to `NVARCHAR`: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86233

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - it is unclear whether you "have to" change it.  Different browsers work differently.  My link recommends `<meta...>` for the top of html, and an attribute for `<form...>`, but I have not checked all the versions of browsers to see which ones are defaulting to `UTF-8`.  At least this _seems_ to be the direction they are going.

Comment: I dont know, is it a bug or not (maybe it's ok when it generates this expression). I have create my database in `MySQL Workbench`. And I was editing my database only in this app, so it can be a bug of MySQL Workbench, not MySQL.